# Calculating the norm of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

So I've been given the matrix A

```
A = [1 2; 3 1]
```

and the question is:

If v is an error vector with ||v|| = 0.01, give an upper bound on ||A^30v||.

||A^30v|| = ||A^30|| * ||v||, correct?

I used the norm function (norm(A^30)), and it gave me a number, but I don't think it's correct:

Basically my question boils down to: Does norm(A^30) return the norm of matrix A^30, because according to matlab index, it returns the largest singular value of A^30. IF norm(A^30) is not what I'm supposed to use, what should I use?

Comment: Just guessing, but I suspect you want the Frobenius norm, `norm(X,'fro')`. Also, keep in mind that there is a difference between `A^30` and `A.^30`.  I don't know which you really want.

Comment: What would the difference be between A^30 and A.^30.

Comment: Some discussion here that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212892/what-is-the-norm-in-matlab.  This doesn't answer your question but there are 3 good answers that give some discussion on the norm and its usage.

Comment: @JakeCooper The differences is [`mpower`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html) vs element-wise power (see `help punct`).